# How to remove a href tags from a string?

Tags: python, html, regex, string, href

I have some user reviews which was previously scraped from a website and I am trying to clean up the text to do some text analysis. There are several a href tags in the text that I would like to remove. For example, see a portion of text contained in a paragraph:

```
'We had a <a href="/redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Frestaurants.com&amp;amp;s=8b83bf0ff8b716aae84527dc95577a310f201b166dcca25c8ca3824b15703869" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;restaurants.com</a&gt; $25 gift certificate, so we visited this restaurant.'
```

I would like to remove this portion from the string:

```
<a href="/redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Frestaurants.com&amp;amp;s=8b83bf0ff8b716aae84527dc95577a310f201b166dcca25c8ca3824b15703869" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;restaurants.com</a&gt;
```

I am not an expert on regex, so the best I could do so far is:

```
import re
re.sub(r'<a href\S+', '', mytext)
```

But this removes only part of what I want to get rid off as shown below:

```
print(mytext)
'We had a  target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;restaurants.com</a&gt; $25 gift certificate, so we visited this restaurant.'
```

I searched a lot for a solution but could only find one for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124183/remove-a-href-tags-from-a-string-using-regex) and several posts that warn against using regex for parsing html, which I guess does not apply to my case as I am processing a string. I guess if I read more about using regex, I can get this done, but I am looking for a quick solution. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Does the text really have `&gt;` instead of `>`? That's strange...wonder why that's escaped, but not the `<`.

Comment: @David784 Yes, that's right. Someone else scraped the content from a website, so I don't know why those characters are in there.

Comment: See this answer: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
''.join(re.findall('(<a href)(.+?)(/a&gt;)', st)[0])
```

That'll work for your example, if you have multiple href links you could use:

```
[''.join(entry) for entry in re.findall('(<a href)(.+?)(/a&gt;)', st)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I am accepting this answer as it helped solve my problem. I used it slightly differently though. I just used re.sub(r'(<a href)(.+?)(/a&gt;)','',mytext) to remove the href links. Using this code I was able to remove multiple links in a string.

Answer (score 0):

as you are looking for a quick solution. just go for basic and use string manipulation.

```
input_string = 'We had a <a href="/redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Frestaurants.com&amp;amp;s=8b83bf0ff8b716aae84527dc95577a310f201b166dcca25c8ca3824b15703869" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;restaurants.com</a&gt; $25 gift certificate, so we visited this restaurant.'
input_string = input_string.split('<a href')
first_part = input_string[0]
input_string = input_string[-1].split('</a&gt;')
sencond_part = input_string[-1]
new_string = first_part + sencond_part
print(new_string)  # We had a  $25 gift certificate, so we visited this restaurant.
```